# How to increase the horizontal resolution of second smaller screen attached with a laptop screen?

Tags: multiple-monitors, resolution

I am using a second smaller screen (Dell) with my laptop (acer Aspire 15.6"). The resolution of my laptop is **`(1366 x 768)`** but the resolution of the second screen is **`( 1024 x 768 )`**.

**Question:**  How can i have the same resolution on both the screens i.e. **`(1366 x 768)`**.

**PS:** I ran the command `xrandr` and got the following output

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2390 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS1 connected 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 345mm x 194mm
   1366x768       60.0*+
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 connected 1024x768+1366+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       60.0* 
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   848x480        60.0  
   640x480        59.9  
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: You can't! If the second screen only has 1024 pixels across, how can you squish the 1366 pixels in? Or do you wish to crop or distort it?

Comment: @Sparhawk: Thanks for your comment. Actually when i transfer a window from my laptop screen to the smaller screen, then that window appears larger. The only thing i want is that the window should appear in the same size in both the screens.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, but the second screen will appear a little fuzzy as the pixels will be interpolated.  You will be telling xrandr to create a scaling factor for the second screen, so that the desired resolution is squished onto the display.

In a terminal, enter the following command

`xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1024x768 --scale 1.334x1 --panning 1366x768`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The above brought the desired results somehow but there are several other problems. Now, i am getting the same thing in both the screens but i want to use the second screen as an Extra space. Could you please tell me how can i revert back to my previous configuration?

Comment: You could revert the configuration by entering `xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1024x768 --scale 1x1 --panning 1024x768`

Comment: i already tried it. I am able to get the previous resolution but i am still getting the same things on both the screens which i don't want.

Comment: In settings->displays, is your system set to mirror the two displays?

Comment: i checked that part...but it is correct. There i have not selected "mirror images". Moreover, if i select "mirror images" then the resolution of my laptop screen gets decreased so that it can represent the things which are present in smaller screen. But at the moment, my laptop screen is working at its full resolution.

Comment: Interesting - I am unsure what causes the duplication of the windows.  I would probably be tempted to reboot at this point...

Comment: ok, let me try that too :(

Comment: @skm  I just heard about a program named `arandr` which is a GUI front-end to xrandr  --  This may help with your dual-monitor setup

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried it but the same things can be done using the already existing "Monitors" program present in Linux system. It just helps you to set the resolution and position of screens but the resolution of a screen cannot be increased using it.

Comment: I'm sure that there's a solution, but I run only a single monitor and the Xrandr command seems to have a huge variety of options.